# AWS S3 -> Elastic Beanstalk - Mixed content error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a frontend deployed on S3 using https. 
When frontend request backend API (load balancer -> elastic beanstalk) then I got an error: Mixed content. 
I know that it is because I am calling API via HTTP, not https.

My question is:
Should I create a brand new SSL certificate for my LoadBalancer?
And how to do this if my load balancer DNS address looks like this: 
awseb-address.region.elb.amazonaws.com (A Record)

I tried to use this address in Certificate Manager but it is not accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I create a brand new SSL certificate for my LoadBalancer? [...] I tried to use this address in Certificate Manager but it is not accepting it.

You **can't register** a certificate direclty for `awseb-address.region.elb.amazonaws.com`.

This is AWS owned domain. To register a SSL certificate, you need to have **your own domain** that you control. You can acquire one from AWS or on any other domain seller.

However, if already have a domain for your fronted, as you mentioned, then maybe you can use that, and create a subdomain for your ELB. You can have **one certificate for multiple domains**.